# Mock async function in module

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

How can I mock the api return with throw error?

```
it('should display error if request fails', async () => {
  const preventDefault = jest.fn();
  const urlCalled = `${apiHost}/json/aaac.co`;
  const wrapper = mount(<WebsiteLocationSearch />);
  wrapper.find('#host').instance().value = 'aaac.co';
  wrapper.simulate('submit', { preventDefault });

  // getHostLocation should return an promise with error.. how? I tried...
  api.getHostLocation.mockResolvedValue(() => {});

  await fetchMock.flush();
  wrapper.update();
  const errorFields = wrapper.find('.error');
  return expect(errorFields).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

On my component ..

```
import getHostLocation from 'api';

...

async onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    this.setState(setLoading(true));
    const host = this.$form.form('get value', 'host');
    await getHostLocation(host); // how to mock this and throw error?
  } catch (error) {
    this.$form.form('add prompt', 'host', error.message);
  } finally {
    this.setState(setLoading(false));
  }
}
```

The api module it's just helper to use api

```
// api module
export default function getHostLocation(host) {
  return fetch(`${apiHost}/json/${host}`)
}
```

Comment: Just `api.getHostLocation.mockImplementation(() => { throw 'error' })` ?

Comment: I have tried..  but error `mockImplementation is not a function`

Comment: How do you mock `getHostLocation`? `jest.spyOn(api, 'getHostLocation').mockImplementation(() => { throw 'error' })` ?